# How to do silent printing without print preview and dialog in Laravel?

Tags: javascript, laravel-5.8

Anyone who have an idea of silent printing in any printer either thermal, inkjet, etc.? I've been searching it and I had a hard time. Some are deprecated already. I've been searching in the 2019 version. In my project, after clicking create, I redirect it on the show where the print layout and is shown. I want that it would print directly without showing the layout and refresh the page.

Comment: What? Is this related to javascript or your printer?

Comment: Javascript and Laravel

Answer (score 0):

There aren't direct ways for printing a web page without showing the print preview dialogue box and older methods such as using flash don't work anymore. However, if you can spare a few JavaScript lines, you can use qz.io.

QZ is a tray application which runs in the background and will communicate with webpage javascript using WebSocket and using that web socket you can send print commands to both Thermal printers and Inkjet/Laser printers.

Read more about QZ here: https://qz.io/

It's really simple to use the library and the tray application. Just install the tray application (you'd need to sign your own certificate or purchase one from QZ company) and then call print method of QZ from JavaScript on your page.

Example from QZ Wiki, this would print `pdf_sample.pdf` file.

```
var config = qz.configs.create("Printer Name");
var data = [{ 
      type: 'pixel',
      format: 'pdf',
      flavor: 'file'
      data: 'assets/pdf_sample.pdf' 
}];
qz.print(config, data).catch(function(e) { console.error(e); });
```

Comment: Is there also a tutorial with qz and laravel just in case?

Comment: @BossPogs you only need the JavaScript library to print with QZ. Just create your layout from Laravel, output it to either a PDF file to HTML. Use QZ to print that HTML or PDF file.

Comment: Thanks sir. I'll try that one and hope silent printing will work.